# How to upgrade SAMBA on 10.04?

Tags: upgrade, 10.04, samba

On Ubuntu 10.04 there is an old samba 3.4.7 how can I upgrade it to the latest
3.5.13 or 3.6.3?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~automation/+archive/ppa) page and it has samba 3.6 for Lucid. The PPA was updated 9 days ago so I think it should be valid. Installation would be...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:automation/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade samba
```

Comment: Please leave rep or a comment if this does not work for you (not going to mess around with my system to see if it does ;) )

Comment: The question was asked couple of months ago. I think I have upgraded by just using backports